# Can I build Docker images in Windows and deploy into Openshift?

Tags: windows, docker, openshift, docker-for-windows

Can I build Docker images in Windows 10 using Docker For Windows and deploy the it into Openshift?

Should I use Linux Container provided by Docker for Windows?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. Build a docker image locally then login to Openshift and docker registry, then you should be able to push the image to registry.

You can find instructions on how to push the image to the internal image registry of OpenShift so it can be deployed at:

- http://cookbook.openshift.org/image-registry-and-image-streams/how-do-i-push-an-image-to-the-internal-image-registry.html